# What is the Makefile Target `.c.o` for?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Someone recently mentioned the target `.c.o` in Makefiles for cross compatability, but I fail to understand its purpose. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's an [old-fashioned suffix rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules).  The more up-to-date way to do it is to use a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
%.o : %.c
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a canned rule for translating `.c` files, i.e. C modules, to `.o` object files. It exists so you don't have to write this rule yourself and is parameterized by Make variables such as `CC` (the C compiler to use), `CFLAGS` (compiler flags), etc.

So, if you use this implicit rule to compile C modules and don't tinker with any Make variables, then the person building your code can specify a compiler and flags on the command line without editing the Makefile.

Comment: but you can do that with the pattern rule as well: `make "CC = gcc"` for example

Comment: @chacham15: that's right. `.c.o` is the older way of doing this.